# SignPost Content Popup Cross Button Issue

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

I am using signpost logic in my code. on cross button of this signpost popup(given on top-right corner). i need to set a variable value to false. but this cross button is provided by clarity. so it is not in my control.

So how can i set a variable value to false on click of cross button?

[image: X]

Comment: It seems like you want to set the value of a property when the signpost is closed, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

By using the de-sugarized syntax for the `*clrIfOpen` directive (see [the angular documentation on two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)), you can use our `(clrIfOpenChange)` output to react to the signpost closing.

Here is an example of it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/if-open-change?file=src/app/app.component.html

Also, as a general rule, please post a direct link to your StackBlitz reproductions when asking a question. Posting a screenshot makes no sense when you went through the trouble of writing a minimal reproduction, it just prevents us from trying it out ourselves.